# Ora2Pg fails to generate sql script with export type containing COPY in conf file

Tags: oracle, postgresql, data-migration, ora2pg

I am using ora2pg to migrate schema and data from oracle to postgres database.

The conf file has following modification:

1. Provided ORACLE_HOME and DSN
2. Set Export type as: `TYPE, TABLE, PACKAGE, COPY, VIEW, GRANT, SEQUENCE, TRIGGER, FUNCTION, PROCEDURE, TABLESPACE, TYPE, PARTITION, MVIEW, QUERY`
   (Removed FDW)

When I run the tool I get the following error:

> DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-01741: illegal zero-length
>   identifier (DBD E RROR: OCIStmtPrepare) [for Statement "SELECT  FROM
>   ""."GT_LAYER_ENTITIES" a"] at  D:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Ora2Pg.pm
>   line 8808. FATAL: ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier (DBD
>   ERROR: OCIStmtPrepare) Aborting export...

The user that I am providing has DBA priviledges.

Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: `FROM ""."GT_LAYER_ENTITIES"` - there is a schema (=user in oracle) missing. I guess you need to add that information to the Ora2Pg configuration.

Comment: Yes the blank in ""."GT_LAYER_ENTITIES" is for MDSYS schema. I think this is oracle spatial schema. But I don't understand why do I need to export it. I have provided the datasource sid = <my database name> in DSN setting in conf file and that's all the data that I need. Shouldn't this tool do the transfer from oracle specific schema to Postgres specific schema. Anyways from what is mentioned at http://ora2pg.darold.net/config.html I set SCHEMA MDSYS. after this it gives the same error for another table "".<some other SDO table>. Even setting EXPORT_SCHEMA 1 has no effect.

Comment: Why are you exporting the MDSYS schema? That is an Oracle internal schema. I very much doubt that you need that in Postgres. You should only export the schema(s) where your application data is stored.

Comment: I replaced SCHEMA MDSYS with SCHEMA <myschema>. But this leads to  : 0 tables,packages... to export, so added EXPORT_SCHEMA 1, still it gives 0 tables, packages...to export, please check whats wrong with this, In my conf file I have : ORACLE_DSN dbi:Oracle:host=<ip>;sid=<myschema>
ORACLE_USER user
ORACLE_PWD user EXPORT_SCHEMA    1 SCHEMA <myschema>  and the above export types TABLES,PACKAGE,COPY....rest is same as default. Please check whats wrong or what else do I need to provide, if I remove export type COPY it exports only schema, then what is with COPY that needs to be added to conf file

Answer (score 1):

You do install the correct version of `DBD-Oracle`. You can prove with `DBD-Oracle-1.74`. 
My advice, you don't use the configuration file for extract tables, view ect. 
But first create a new project:

```
ora2pg --project_base /home/user/ --init_project project_name

cd project_name/

ora2pg -c ora2pg.conf -t TABLE -o tables.sql -b schema/tables/

ora2pg -c ora2pg.conf -t SEQUENCE -o sequence.sql -b schema/sequences/

ora2pg -c ora2pg.conf -t TRIGGER -o trigger.sql -b schema/triggers/

ora2pg -c ora2pg.conf -t PROCEDURE -o procedure.sql -b schema/procedures

ora2pg -c ora2pg.conf -t VIEW -o view.sql -b schema/views/

ora2pg -c ora2pg.conf -t GRANT -o grant.sql -b schema/grants/
```

and after import on db postgres tables, sequence, etc...
Finally, import the data on db.

```
ora2pg -c ora2pg.conf -t INSERT -o data.sql -b data/
```

It's most important that you firt create a psql database and user for your import.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it is not possible to export multiple stuff at the same time using ora2pg

Only one type of export can be perform at the same time so the TYPE directive must be unique. If you have more than one only the last found in the file will be registered.

[image]